# Error: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1x3, op2 is 1x2)

Tags: image-processing, octave, detection

I am trying to do stone detection in Octave and this is error happening:

> error: imarithmetics: mx_el_eq: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1x3, op2 is 1x2)
>   error: called from; imarithmetics at line 35 column 13; imadd at line 43 column 12; stones at line 24 column 7

I want to superposition the erode image with the original one. I can't figure it out what to do with this.

```
pkg load image

img = imread ('stones.jpg');
bw = rgb2gray(img);

k = ones(3,3)/9;
m = imfilter(bw,k);
K = wiener2 (m, [5 5]);
subplot(1,3,1),imshow(bw);
subplot(1,3,2),imshow(m);
subplot(1,3,3),imshow(K);

thresh = im2bw(K);
figure, imshow(thresh);


se = strel("square", 3);
se =[1, 1, 1;1, 1, 1;1, 1, 1];
OP = imerode(thresh, se);
OP = imerode(OP, se);
OP = imerode(OP, se);
figure, imshow(OP);

final = imadd(img,OP,'uint16'); %<< Line 24, error happens here
figure, imshow(final);
```

Comment: Did you try `img + OP`? What are the sizes of `img` and `OP` at that point in the code?

Comment: If I try to do img + OP it says that error: edge: IM must be a grayscale image. Im kinda new to this language, how can I see the size of each image?