# Octave: How to assign the right dimensionality to an existing cell array to avoid "error: =: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 2x2x2, op2 is 2x2x2)"?

Tags: multidimensional-array, arguments, octave, cell-array

I am a beginner at Octave, that is why I will share something too obvious for the most.

```
cell_arr = cell(2,2,2);
cell_arr(2,2,2) = cell(2,2,2);
```

> error: =: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 2x2x2, op2 is 2x2x2)

I am assigning an array of the same dimensionality as the cell_array, and it is not accepted. What should I change?

---

This is a spin-off from [Please Explain Octave-Error : operator /: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1x1, op2 is 1x10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56759719/please-explain-octave-error-operator-nonconformant-arguments-op1-is-1x1-o) and [Error: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1x3, op2 is 1x2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56979544/error-nonconformant-arguments-op1-is-1x3-op2-is-1x2) which both do not deal with cell arrays.

Comment: The big question is, what are you _trying_ to do?

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou I did not mean to try anything here. I have a more complex assignment to do and the simple examples shall show that on the left side, when filtering a given cell array, only ":" format can choose multiple items, and then you need to be aligned with that on the right. If you just take cell_array (2,2,2) on the left, it is just 1 item per dimension. Thus, the whole thing is just for this very basic insight, beginner level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you're trying to do, but your understanding of cells seems to be a bit confused.

To make matters worse, I think you are coming across a bug: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=59637

I don't want to get too technical and confuse you even more, but what is happening here is this. We usually introduce cell arrays by saying this little story:

> "There are two kinds of arrays: normal arrays, and cell arrays. Normal arrays always need to be 'rectangular', and contain elements of the same type. Cell arrays on the other hand, can contain elements of different types."

However, this isn't exactly true. It's a simplification. In reality, a 'cell' is simply a special kind of object; a container if you like. And a cell array then, is simply a normal array, whose elements are all 'cell objects'. In fact, the `cell` *command* is simply a shortcut way for creating an array of empty cells, nothing more.

More generally, cell arrays are indexed using `{}`, which opens up the cell object, and gives you its *contents*.

However, since they can also be thought of as normal arrays of 'cell objects', you can also index it with `()` like a normal array, and return the 'cell object' itself (as opposed to its *contents*).

E.g.

```
a = cell(1,2)   # this is equivalent to a = { [], [] }
a{1}   # returns an empty numerical array, which is what the first cell contains.
a(1)   # returns a cell object, which happens to contain an empty numerical array.
```

Regarding the bug you're coming across, octave seems to report the wrong size for the elements you're trying to access when it comes to multidimensional cell arrays. This has been reported. What you *should* have been getting was something like

```
Error: op1 is 1x1, op2 is 2x2x2
```

In other words: "you are trying to cram a 2x2x2 array (whose elements happen to be cell objects) into a space that only fits a single element (i.e. at position 2,2,2)."

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is that a new cell array can only be assigned to an existing cell array if the dimensions are exactly the same.

```
cell_arr = cell(2,2,2);
x = cell(2,2,2);
cell_arr(2,2,2) = x;
```

The last line causes an error, since cell_arr(2,2,2) chooses just the second item of each dimension, *and not the 2 items of each dimension*. Instead, only the initialisation of cell(2,2,2) builds a cell array of 2 items for each dimension.

It is thus important on which side you are, and whether you initiate or re-use a cell array.

The following works:

```
cell_arr(:,:,:) = x;
cell_arr(1:2,1:2,1:2) = x;
cell_arr(1:end,1:end,1:end) = x;
cell_arr(:,:,:) = x(1:2,1:2,1:2);
cell_arr(:,:,:) = x(:,:,:);
cell_arr(:,:,:) = x(1:end,1:end,1:end);
```

Of course, a directly initiated cell array can also be assigned:

```
cell_arr(:,:,:) = cell(1:2,1:2,1:2);
```

and this does not work with "end", since it does not exist till then:

```
cell_arr(1:end,1:end,1:end) = cell(1:end,1:end,1:end);
```

> error: invalid use of 'end': may only be used to index existing value

Thus the solution is as follows, if you want to assign something to `cell_arr(2,2,2)`:

Right: Two cell arrays of 2x2x2 are created.

```
cell_arr = cell(2,2,2);
x = cell(2,2,2);
```

And then:

Left: Only the 2nd item of each dim is chosen = 1x1. Right: Thus, only one item can be chosen per dim, for example the first item as follows:

```
cell_arr(2,2,2) = x(1,1,1);
```